# React-native returning promise in render() and correct result in console.log function

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

Maybe my question is just a geek mistake.
Let's suppose a simple form class that uses RNFS (itinance/react-native-fs)

```
class myform1 extends Component<{}> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
    };
  }

  async _myfunction(dir_name) {

    try {

      const response = await RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + dir_name);

      const r = await response;

      console.log(r); //-> here, it show the correct result

      return r;

    } catch(e){ console.log(e) }

  }
```

This console.log prints the correct result: objects with the files in directory name.
But if I try to console.log() the result in render(), on class, the result is not showable, but just the promise:

Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}

Here is the code for my class:

```
componentDidMount(){

    ...some_stuffs_to_do...

}
render() {
      return(
        <View>
            {
                some_variable.map((key, index) => {

                const test = this._myfunction(dir_name);

                console.log('on form: ');
                console.log(test); //-> here, it show "Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}"
            }
            ...

            <Text>Just example</Text>
        </View>
     );
}
```

I try a lot of things to solve this, but I did not make it.

Any good soul to help me, please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: An `async` function will always return a `Promise`. So `test` is a promise

Comment: Add `await` before calling _myFunction since it's a Promise.  `const test = await this._myfunction(dir_name);` But this is not a good approach. Try to get `_myfunction`'s responses and outside of the render method.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of an `async` method will always be a Promise. So the value returned by `_myfunction` is a Promise. In your `componentDidMount()` method, you can extract the value in the promise returned by `_myfunction` using `.then()`. You can then update the `state`'s `test` property and use that states `test` property in your `render()` method:

```
...
componentDidMount(){
  // other code...

  Promise.all(some_variable.map((key, index) => {
    return this._myfunction(dir_name);
  }).then((mapped_arr) => {
    this.setState({mapped_arr});
  }); 
}

render() {
  return(
    <View>
      {this.state.mapped_arr}
    </View>
  );
}
...
```

Comment: I can't use componentDidMount() because I call this function in a "some_variable.map((key, index) =>"... any other suggestion, please?

Comment: `.map()` everything in `some_variable` to the `Promise` returned by `_myfunction`. Then use `Promise.all()` on this array of promises and set the state of `mapped_arr` to the result of Promise.all. You can then render this mapped array in your `render()` method by accessing it from the state

Comment: @MuriloMartinatti its not clear though what you're trying to do with `.map()`. At the moment you're not returning from the `.map()` function and you're creating a bunch of the exact same `test` variables as you're always passing in the same argument